# How to passing the data from tap() to takewhile()

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to build a function to check if the inserted data is valid.

Below is my code, which will have a `map()` and a `take()` function to make sure the checking function will not run more 10 times.

What I am trying to do is want to run `chk_data_status()` to get back the status by using `tap()` and return that status to `takeWhile()` so that the whole function will stop if the status is not in status "Processing".

But the problem is that the `takeWhile()` function gets the value of count from the `map()` and `take()` function instead of `res.status` from `tap()`.

```
const count = 10
timer(5000, 1000)
    .pipe(
        map(i => count- i),
        take(count + 1),
        tap(async () => {
            let res: any = await this.chk_data_status(id); // return as a Promise
            console.log(res.status);
            return res.status;
        }),
        takeWhile((status: any) => {
            console.log(status);
            return status!= 'Processing';
        }),
        finalize(() => doSomething())
    ).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tap operator doesn't return a value instead passes whatever it received, hence you get what is in the map. Simply replace tap with map and your takeWhile() will get the status.

Also instead of using async and wait, why don't you just pipe your request as below,

```
const count = 10
timer(5000, 1000)
 .pipe(
   map(i => count- i),
   take(count + 1),
   mergeMap(_ => this.chk_data_status(id).pipe(map( res =>  res.status))),
   takeWhile((status: any) => {
     console.log(status);
     return status!= 'Processing';
  }),
  finalize(() => doSomething())
).subscribe();
```

But then make sure `this.chk_data_status(id)` returns an observable.

Comment: If the order matters, you might want to go for `concatMap`